# Coalescing/merging rows but retaining "dominant" values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, character, aggregate

My problem seems rather trivial but appearantly I didn't come up with the appropriate search terms.

My data is like this:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,3,3),
                   V1 = c("A","B","A","B","C"),
                   V2 = c("C","B",NA,"B","A"),
                   V3 = c("A","B","C","B",NA))
```

I want to coalesce or merge the rows by ID and keep only one row per ID with the "highest" value in each column. In my example, I would like to prioritize C over B over A.

After the desired operation, my data would look like this:

```
| ID | V1 | V2 | V3 |
| -- | -- | -- | -- |
|  1 | B  | C  | B  |
|  2 | A  | NA | C  |
|  3 | C  | B  | B  |
```

Any hints would be greatly appreciated! Dplyr is preferred, but no necessity. Thanks!

Edit: The solutions (thank you for that!) all took advantage of the fact that letters are "ordered" in R.

Let us take this example data:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,3,3),
                   V1 = c("yes","no","yes","no","unsure"),
                   V2 = c("unsure","no",NA,"no","yes"),
                   V3 = c("yes","no","unsure","no",NA))
```

Where the desired outcome is that the priority is "yes" over "no" over "unsure".

Comment: It sounds like you might alternately phrase this as "I would like to prioritize B over C over A."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: added simpler dplyr-only

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(across(V1:V3, max))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
     ID V1    V2    V3   
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 B     C     B    
2     2 A     NA    C    
3     3 C     B     NA
```

If you want ordered factors, here's an approach where we specify the ordering, apply that to the data in V1:V3, and then proceed as before.

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,3,3),
                   V1 = c("yes","no","yes","no","unsure"),
                   V2 = c("unsure","no",NA,"no","yes"),
                   V3 = c("yes","no","unsure","no",NA))

var_order <- c("yes", "no", "unsure")


# Note addition of `ordered = TRUE` to make the `min` work
data %>%
  mutate(across(V1:V3, ~factor(.x, levels = var_order, ordered = TRUE))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(across(V1:V3, ~min(., na.rm = TRUE)))


# A tibble: 3 × 4
     ID V1    V2    V3    
  <dbl> <ord> <ord> <ord> 
1     1 yes   no    yes   
2     2 yes   NA    unsure
3     3 no    yes   no
```

---

Earlier solution using reshaping from tidyr. This worked without the `ordered = TRUE` flag set, but would be inefficient for larger data sets.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
data %>%
  mutate(across(V1:V3, ~factor(.x, levels = var_order))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  group_by(ID, name) %>%
  slice_min(value) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name)


# A tibble: 3 × 4
     ID V1    V2    V3    
  <dbl> <fct> <fct> <fct> 
1     1 yes   no    yes   
2     2 yes   NA    unsure
3     3 no    yes   no
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Your approach works because letters are "ordered" in R. I should have made my question more precise: I want to be able to customize the priority, like B over C over A, as in my real data the strings I am dealing with are not in alphabetical order.

Comment: It will probably be simplest then to convert your values in V1:V3 into ordered factors that are ordered the way you want.

Comment: That sounds entirely reasonable. Thank you very much!

Comment: See edit for an example using ordered factors.

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your most helpful solution. May I ask why you opted for a pivot approach here? With bigger datasets these become quite resource intensive in my experience. I now simply converted the strings to factors, ordered them, converted them to numeric wihin the first mutate-function, then applied your dplyr-solution and converted the numerics back to characters with a second mutate-function (case_when()).

Comment: Edited to do it with the first solution, which can be as you note more efficient for larger data sets. One change I needed to make (which you circumvented by converting to numerics) was setting the `ordered = TRUE` flag; this allows us to use `min`/`max` on the factors themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Since we can can get the maximum for a letter from the alphabet, We could use:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ max(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     ID V1    V2    V3   
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 B     C     B    
2     2 A     <NA>  C    
3     3 C     B     B
```

Comment: `%>% summarise_all(max, na.rm = T)` would be a little more concise

Comment: Nope. With the release of dplyr 1.0.0 (IIRC), the `..._all` versions of verbs have been superseded in favour of `across()`. See `?summarize_all`: "Scoped verbs (_if, _at, _all) have been superseded by the use of across() in an existing verb. See vignette("colwise") for details."

Comment: Cool, didn't know that. Not sure if I find it better though. Anyway +1

Comment: ```mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)``` we need this as well

Comment: IF the data contains factor columns, then yes. The provided sample data from the TO does not.

Comment: Depends on your R version. `stringsAsFactors` equals to `TRUE` by default for the older versions. Anyhow, you're not wrong :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in `base`:

```
aggregate(data[,-1], by = list(ID=data$ID), FUN = max, na.rm = T)

#   ID V1   V2 V3
# 1  1  B    C  B
# 2  2  A <NA>  C
# 3  3  C    B  B
```